# Websocket timeout

Tags: javascript, websocket, timeout

I need to handle a websocket timeout when the socket is trying to connect to a server available but busy.

More in deep I have a web application that can connect to several single-thread remote socket server in charge to post-process data passed as input.

The goal is to collect data from web GUI and then submit them to the first socket available and listening.

In case a server socket daemon is already processing data, it cannot serve the user request that has instead to be addressed to the second socket of the list.

Basically and with a practical example, I have such socket ready to accept a call coming from a web brworser:

ws://10.20.30.40:8080/
ws://10.20.30.40:8081/
ws://10.20.30.40:8082/
ws://10.20.30.40:8083/
ws://192.192.192.192:9001/

When the first socket receive the call and perform handshake, it starts to process data (and this process may took some minutes).

When another client do the same request on a different set of data, I would like that that the request is served by the 2nd socket available and so on.

So the question is... how can I contact the socket (the first of the list), wait 250 milliseconds and (in case of timeout) skip to the next one?

I've started from the following approach:

```
$.interval = function(func, wait, times) {
    var interv = function(w, t) {
        return function() {
            if (typeof t === "undefined" || t-- > 0) {
                setTimeout(interv, w);
                try {
                    func.call(null);
                } catch(e) {
                    t = 0;
                    throw e.toString();
                }
            } else {
                alert('stop');
            }
        };
    } (wait, times);
    setTimeout(interv, wait);
}

handler = new WebSocket(url);
loop = 1;
$.interval(function(){
    rs = handler.readyState;
    console.log("(" + loop++ + ") readyState: " + rs);
}, 25, 10); //loop 10 times every 25 milliseconds
```

But how can I stop in case the socket.readyState became 1 (OPEN) or the limit is reached?

Comment: Your question is not clear (at least it is not to me). You have a web app that accepts ws:// connections and sends them to background workers, but you try to select the background worker directly from the browser? Is that it?

Comment: I have a web application in charge to collect data from users.
Once collected and onsubmit button these data has to be depolyied to a remote daemon available on several server in charge to analyze data and provide a solution.
These remote daemons are listening on a socket:  ws://10.20.30.40:8080/  ws://10.20.30.40:8081/  ws://10.20.30.40:8082/  ws://10.20.30.40:8083/  ws://192.192.192.192:9001/   
Considering so that  a.websocket are asyncronus  b.only the first socket available must serve the request  how can I query each socket addressing the request ONLY to the first available?

Comment: Why not have the workers behind a web application? The browsers can establish a ws:// connection to the web app and send the data there. The web app selects an available worker and sends it the data. If no worker is available the data is queued on the web app until one becomes available. Once the result is obtained from the worker, the web app sends the response to the client. Due to the nature of websockets, you can send a response to the client whenever you want and the client can just wait patiently for a response and not care about any workers at all. Have you considered such a setup?

Comment: No. I did not considered such approach, @Bogdan but I think that's a good approach!